# How do I transfer a value from a text box to a new window using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have created a form so the user can complete his name, last name, credit card number etc.

All the information is provided by the user.

When the user has ended his work he should press a button and a new window pops up with the user's information revised.

Anyone has a suggestion on this? I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
opener.document.getElementById("text").value = txt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.
Firstly, this code is only for  window that pops up from the parent form?Or can i create a new document and connect these two pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the child window from the parent one and vice-versa. When you open a popup window with `window.open(url, options)`, it returns a reference to the child window. You can add handlers to it. Using jquery:

```
var w = window.open(url); 
$(w).load(function() {
  alert("I've just loaded");
});
```

From the child window, you can use the variable `opener` to reference the parent window. So if you want to grab info from the parent window, you'll use something like (again jquery):

```
var first_name = $(opener.document).find('.first-name').text();
```

Got this info here: http://sharkysoft.com/tutorials/jsa/content/053.html

From a user experience point of view, if you just want to open a popup to confirm the data, without server side processing, I find opening a popup disturbing and would rather use an overlay on the same page.